# The union of countably infinite sets make up an uncountably infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Can this happen?

We know the theorem that a union of countably infinite sets is countable, but can we, for example, take a union of countably infinite sets (not necessarily mutually exclusive) and get $\mathbb{R}$, which is uncountably infinite?

I can surmise no way, because I know that $\mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{I}=\mathbb{R}$. Any suggestions?

Comment: The irrationals aren't countable so that is not a union of countable sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very easy to write $\mathbb{R}$ as a union of countable sets:

$$ \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{ x \} $$

If you really want to insist on each set being infinite, you can do something like

$$ \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left( \{ x \} \cup \mathbb{Z} \right)$$

You can even arrange for all of the individual sets to be disjoint! e.g.

$$ \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{x \in [0,1)} \{ x + n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$

---

You're misremembering the theorem: it's only a *countable* union of countable sets that's guaranteed to be countable. Each of the examples above is an *uncountable* union of countable sets.

Comment: Beat me, +1!${}{}{}$

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit confused. It is *not true* that a union of countable sets need be countable: only that a *countable union* of countable sets is countable. For example, the reals can be written as a union of countable (indeed, *finite*) sets: $$\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{x\};$$ the point is that we need *uncountably* many sets to do so.

---

Interestingly, we need the axiom of choice to show that a countable union of countable sets is countable; but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

A countable union of countable sets is countable, which can be proven by a diagonalization argument. An arbitrary union of countable sets may not be countable though.

Consider $\cup \{x\}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: "which can be proven by a diagonalization argument" Huh? It's not really diagonalization in any sense that I'm aware of . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber The enumeration of pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers in order of increasing $a+b$ and, for equal $a+b$, in order of increasing $a$ is often called "Cantor's first diagonal argument", because it proceeds along (short) diagonals in the array $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. In this connection, what we usually call a diagonal argument is called "Cantor's second diagonal argument".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks - I did not know that! I retract my previous comment (but I'll leave it up so that your response, which I think is useful and interesting, makes sense most easily).

Comment: @AndreasBlass But don't the words "diagonalize" and "diagonalization" refer only to Cantor's second diagonal argument?

Comment: @bof I don't think "diagonalize"is so precisely defined. I use it only in the sense of Cantor's second diagonal argument, but I don't complain if other people use it in a broader sense.